# Having issues with htaccess rewrite for vBulletin

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vbulletin

Here is my htaccess. I have noticed that when I click on the link for the classifieds mod, it redirects me back to the main forum. I know that the htaccess is setup to redirect back to https, and is working great -  not sure what is going on. Any help appreciated. The code in question is the OZZMODZ portion below...

```
# Use PHP 5.3
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php .html .htm


<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com [R=301,L]

# If you are having problem with "None Could Be Negotiated" errors in Apache, uncomment this to turn off MultiViews
 Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\.php)
RewriteRule ^((archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?))$ xxxxxxxx.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ xxxxxxxxxxx.php [L,QSA]

**RewriteRule ^classifieds/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=main&catid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sale/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^wanted/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^trade/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^offer/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=viewitem&itemid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^seller/([^/]*)/ ./ozzmodz_classifieds.php?do=seller&sellerid=$1 [L,NC]**

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|css|flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|pdf|png|svg|swf|tif|tiff)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A604800
ExpiresByType text/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType text/css A604800
ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A604800
ExpiresByType image/icon A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpg A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
ExpiresByType image/png A604800
ExpiresByType text/html A604800
</IfModule>
```